# SVN, can check out repository on server but not on client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I configured an SVN repository on a shared managed server and followed these steps.

```
svnadmin create ~/public_html/myrep
```

Configured `svnserve.conf`, including `anon-access = read` for test purposes. And imported a test project.

```
svn import ~/public_html/tmp file:///usr/home/myurl/public_html/myrep/project
```

Started the daemon...

```
svnserve -d -r /usr/home/myurl/public_html/
```

Now all of that works like a charm and I can actually checkout the repository on the server itself via `svn://` protocol (absolute path and URL).

```
svn co svn://myurl.com/myrep/project
```

When I try the same checkout on my Window 10 client running TortoiseSVN I get the following error message.

```
Error    Unable to connect to a repository at URL ....
```

Any ideas how to solve this or isolate the issue? I already switched off the local firewall as well.

Any helpful comments would be appreciated.

Comment: write **FULL** error message

Answer (score 0):

Remote client implies at least **two failure points**: server and client.

If you have disabled firewalling server-side, you have to check it from client-side (without TSVN): telnet on svn-port of server, after it you have to inspect network settings of TortoiseSVN (which version? pre-1.9.2 in 1.9.* known as very buggy)